# Stack Overflow software available?

Tags: discussion

Do you sell or otherwise make available the software for SO?

I was surprised that the forum at http://forums.reflector.net looks so much like SO. Did they copy you out of admiration and respect, or did they get the software from you?

Comment: (Isn't your display name too confusing for others, to [use in comment replies](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work/43020#43020)? Sure, when one knows the rules, it's easy. But folks just using `@P a u l` will break the notifications?)

Answer (score 4):

That's a [OSQA](http://www.osqa.net/) (Stack Overflow clone) site most likely according to this script name.

http://forums.reflector.net/m/reflect/media/js/osqa.main.js

You can search more info about OSQA related posts [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=osqa) at meta or take a look at [known clone lists](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2267/stack-overflow-clones)

Answer (score 2):

Stack Exchange no longer offers a subscription service nor licenses the software to host your own Stack Exchange sites. Stack Exchange sites can only be created through the democratic, community-driven process at [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/faq).

Comment: Hehe, no word on the "admiration and respect", huh? ;-) (I fail to see admiration and respect in trying to make —or use— an exact copy, but well...)